# Uncaught ReferenceError: uploadFile is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

Working through a firebase tutorial and keep getting the error that uploadFile is not defined. this is the code snippet in my index.html file

```
<body>
    <h3>Storage Uploads</h3>
    <input type="file" onchange="uploadFile(this.files)" />
    <hr />
    <img id="imgUpload" src="" width="100vw" />
  </body>
```

this is my app.js function

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  const app = firebase.app();
  console.log(app);
});
function uploadFile(files) {
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  const horseRef = storageRef.child("horse.jpg");

  const file = files.item(0);
  const task = horseRef.put(file);

  task.then((snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot);
    const url = snapshot.downloadURL;
    document.querySelector("#imgUpload").setAttribute("src", url);
  });
}
```

ive tried clearing the cache, ending the firebase serve, tried firebase deploy and am still getting that the function is undefined. Any help would be appreciatted

Comment: My guess is that your `app.js` is included as a module, in which case this is the expected behavior as `uploadFile` is not an exported, top-level function. The simplest fix is to attach it to `window`, so `window.uploadFile = (files) => { ... rest of your code }`.

Comment: window.uploadFile = (files) => {
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  const horseRef = storageRef.child("horse.jpg");

  const file = files.item(0);
  const task = horseRef.put(file);

  task.then((snapshot) => {
    console.log("snapshot", snapshot);
    snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      document.querySelector("#imgUpload").setAttribute("src", url);
    });
  });
};